# Javascript console : detect history of function calls

Tags: javascript

I am working on a code which I have not written myself, and I would like to know if it would be possible to detect which functions are called by Javascript. Does any console do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: console.error in some browsers adds a stack trace - will that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Chrome Developer Tools to debugger your code (F12).

In Sources panel you can define your own breakpoint (in the code or event listener). Then you could analyze the code, and include counters etc.

Also you can see the stack trace of any function.

Answer (score 3):

Everywhere you want to see stacktrace you can do this:

```
 console.log(new Error().stack)
```

---

[image]

Comment: Just doing `console.trace()` seems simpler to me…

Comment: You right. I am like to use `error.stack`, because `console.trace`, not bring back String. You cannot do for example `copy(console.trace())` for copied to clipboard, or using `error().stack.match` for searching for text in the stack trace

Answer (score 1):

i think you can learn more about debugging in  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging